# Composite Observable

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have the following code:

```
Observable.FromEvent<ModelEventArgs>(
        h => ValuesController.ModelAdded += h,
        h => ValuesController.ModelAdded -= h)
    .Subscribe(m => context.Connection.Broadcast(m));

Observable.FromEvent<ModelEventArgs>(
        h => ValuesController.ModelDeleted += h,
        h => ValuesController.ModelDeleted -= h)
    .Subscribe(m => context.Connection.Broadcast(m));
```

What would be cleaner would be:

```
Observable.[SOMETHING](
        Observable.FromEvent<ModelEventArgs>(
                h => ValuesController.ModelAdded += h,
                h => ValuesController.ModelAdded -= h),
        Observable.FromEvent<ModelEventArgs>(
                h => ValuesController.ModelDeleted += h,
                h => ValuesController.ModelDeleted -= h))
    .Subscribe(m => context.Connection.Broadcast(m));
```

I can't seem to figure out what that [SOMETHING] needs to be, I don't want to wait for ModelAdded to Complete, i just want them both to emit (m) for each event.

Go easy on me, I'm an Rx newb

Comment: You can probably switch to [FromEventPattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229221%28v=vs.103%29.aspx), it's a bit cleaner.

Comment: Most documentation uses the .FromEvent<T> method, and I'd rather have type safety than save a line of code passing a string

Comment: @JoeFlateau - They changed the name from `FromEvent` to `FromEventPattern` but then reintroduced `FromEvent` with a different purpose! `FromEvent` is for non-standard events. `FromEventPattern` is for the standard pattern. Both are available in strongly-typed overloads. You should use `FromEventPattern`.

Comment: Well shoot... I kinda like my little baby Action<T>s over big brother EventHandler<T>

Comment: @JoeFlateau - Sorry, if you're using `Action<T>` then use `FromEvent` by all means. That's why it's there. I assumed you were using standard events because of the `ModelEventArgs` class name.

Comment: Oh, @JoeFlateau, don't forget to do the @ Enigmativity in your comment otherwise I would generally not see your reply. It was just luck that I refreshed the page.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you're looking for `Merge`:

```
Observable.Merge(
        Observable.FromEvent<ModelEventArgs>(
                h => ValuesController.ModelAdded += h,
                h => ValuesController.ModelAdded -= h),
        Observable.FromEvent<ModelEventArgs>(
                h => ValuesController.ModelDeleted += h,
                h => ValuesController.ModelDeleted -= h))
    .Subscribe(m => context.Connection.Broadcast(m));
```

Comment: Thanks, I did see that but thought it wasn't working.

Turns out my Deleted Broadcast is breaking SignalR (silently) and that's why i didn't catch the subsequent Broadcasts